# Permissions problem with my first Laravel dev environment with Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, permissions, file-permissions

I'm switching my development environments from virtual machines (with Vagrant and VirtualBox) to containers with Docker. I successfully set-up a simple dev environment for WordPress and now I'm trying to do the same for Laravel.
I'm on Windows 10 Pro, using WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04 installed).
If I try to on on `localhost:8088` (where my local Laravel installation is exposed) I get:

> *UnexpectedValueException*
> The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    nginx:
        container_name: 'NGINX_Web_Server'
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        depends_on:
            - php
            - mariadb
        ports: 
            - 8088:80
        volumes: 
            - ./root:/var/www/html
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

    php:
        container_name: 'PHP-FPM_7.4'
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes: 
            - ./root:/var/www/html
        ports: 
            - 9090:9000

    mariadb:
        container_name: 'MariaDB_SQL_Server'
        image: mariadb
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        volumes: 
            - ./mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
            MYSQL_USER: ll_user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ll_password
```

this is the `Dockerfile` indicated in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
FROM php:fpm-alpine3.12

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
#RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

and the `default.conf` file for nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

**What's wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Could be solved with:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

chmod -R 755 /var/www/storage
```

If it does not work for you, try this in the container:

- Check: `docker-compose exec php ls -al /var/www/storage`

  I saw `xfs` instead of `www-data`
- Run: `docker-compose exec php chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/storage`
- Run: `docker-compose exec php chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/bootstrap/cache`

Try again and it must work